# How to call php function on page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to call php function that pulls data from database in Wordpress and show results
on page for example.
My function/query is like following way:

```
<?php
     global $wpdb; 
     $myrows=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT ident_broj, ime, prezime FROM marija_radnik_CYR");
     echo $myrows;
?>
```

Comment: myrows is not a string so it will throw an error ! it will be an object, try this echo "<pre>"; print_r($myrows); echo "</pre>"; it will show what is contained in $myrows .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ident_broj, ime, prezime FROM marija_radnik_CYR"); 
   if(!empty($results)) {// do anything }
```

declare wpdb global first and then use it !

Comment: <?php
$myrows=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT ident_broj, ime, prezime FROM marija_radnik_CYR");
                 
            foreach($myrows as $myrow){
   
   echo $myrow->ident_broj;
   echo $myrow->ime;
   echo $myrow->prezime;
   echo "</br>";
   
   }
   
   ?>

Comment: hope you got what you looking for .

Answer (score 0):

```
   $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ident_broj, ime, prezime FROM marija_radnik_CYR" );
   echo $myrows;
```

Do not require to declare $wpdb again if your using the function in already relative wp page

Comment: Yes, thanks I understand cause I'm not calling inside function variable that is on global level!